# Powershell search zip files Windows 10

Tags: powershell, zip

Have a Powershell script version 5.1 that zips all files modified last 24 hours using date as file name within specific directories.  If the script was already run that day, then the time stamp is appended to file name, along with current date.  Used it for years.  You would think I would be able to reverse engineer that code to SEARCH all those zip files for a specific file/files(s) but alas, no.  On my home Windows 7 machine I can simply search through the backup zip directory with Explorer.  Does not work in Windows 10. Cannot change search properties on my work laptop.
Below is some code posted here as a solution to an almost identical request, and writes the results of the files being searched for to a CSV file in a directory.

```
$filePath = "M:\BACKUPS\"
write-host "Path: " $filePath                                                                                                                               

$searchTerms = @( "YOMoma")                                                    
function openZip($zipFile){
    try{                                                                            
        [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" ) | Out-Null;                                                                         
        $zipContens = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipFile);                      
        $zipContens.Entries | % {                                                           
            foreach($searchTerm in $searchTerms){                                                
                if ($_.Name -imatch $searchTerm){                                          
                    Write-Output ($_.Name + "," + $_.FullName + "," + $_.CompressedLength + "," + $_.LastWriteTime + "," + $_.Length);                                                           
                }
            }               
        }
    }
    catch{
        Write-Output ("There was an error:" + $_.Exception.Message);
    }
}  

write-host "SearchTerm: " $searchTerms                                                           

Get-ChildItem -Path -$filePath *.zip -Recurse  | %  {
    openZip $_.FullName  >> $RemotePath = M:\BACKUPS\FOUND\ZIPMATCH.csv
}
```

Error:

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '-M' does not exist.
At M:\SearchZips.ps1:32 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -Path -$filePath *.zip -Recurse  | %  {
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-M:String) [Get-ChildItem], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Declared `$Path="M:\"`, replaced `-Path` with `$Path` to remove this error, but simply got a different error:

```
Get-ChildItem : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '*.zip'.
At M:\SearchZips.ps1:33 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem $Path -$filePath *.zip -Recurse  | %  {
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`enter code here`
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Again, I am using all these functions (and more) in my backup script with no errors such as:

```
Copy-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $BACKUPATH                                            
foreach ($i in $hardrives){
    [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($Source, $Backupzipath)                              
    $Lstfile = @(Get-ChildItem  M:\BACKUPS)
}
```

to make these backup files, (by now there are hundreds at this point), but I can't seem to put 2+2 together.

THX.

Comment: Remove the `-` in front of the variable, so it reads `Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath` (instead of `Get-ChildItem -Path -$filePath`)

Comment: OK, so that was embarrassing.....

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much, we all stare ourselves blind on something from time to time ;-)

Comment: Special thanx to Anonymous for cleaning up my post so the code is clearly separated from my tale of woe. Have not mastered the <CTL> k.                                                     
 If I have any consolation, I did remove the "-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue"  from the original code I found on StackExchange.  Not sure why anyone would include that in an answer.  Theoretically it is  a learning exercise for the poster  - if  you can't see the errors,  you can't learn from your mistakes.   Then again, I could be wrong.